# Why can't I find a 2.2ohm 0.25W 10% resistor

Tags: resistors

I am following the guide to create the Colour Maximite 2 computer (here: https://ufile.io/wv2xo4wg). It is asking for several resistors. Here are some of them:

```
Carbon Film 2.2Ω 0.25W 10% Resistor
Carbon Film 10Ω 0.25W 10% Resistor
Carbon Film 1KΩ 0.25W 10% Resistor
```

It is hard to find the exact resistors. Do I have to have the exact one?

Comment: Digikey has several thousand options to choose from for 2.2 ohm resistors.  Any reason you can't use at least one of those?

Comment: 10% resistors are rare these days - use 5% instead.  The % tolerance indicates how far the resistance can be from the stated vallue, so 5%  is better.

Comment: @PeterBennett thank you for your advice, so will 5% work even if it says 10%?

Comment: Yes - a 1000 Ohm 10% resistor may be anywhere between 900 and 1100 Ohms.  A 5% 1000 Ohm resistor will be between 950 and 1050 Ohms.  In fact, most 5% metal or carbon film resistors will really be within 1% of the marked value.

Comment: Decades ago 10% was common, now 1% tolerance is common. If you need 0.l% tolerance or better, then the price goes up quickly.

Comment: Use a 2 ohm resistor, it is within tolerance - just.

Comment: 1% is market standard.

Comment: @Sparky256 I'm older. I remember when 20% (no band) was common. Aside from the cheaper bakelite construction we used then, the top of the line construction looked more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kc1E.jpg) (that's newer, of course -- uses more expensive and "modern" 10% resistors -- but you get the general idea about how we laid it out back then.) That's when real resistors were ***real resistors*** with ***real uncertainty*** and we didn't blanche at the idea of custom, thick aluminum sheets and cutouts & genuine custom rotary dials and knobs (and lots of them.) 1% is for sissies.

Comment: @jonk Back in the 1960's, the tube days, a burnt cathode resistor was common. They usually cracked and were an easy fix for us TV technicians. Bulky solid carbon. Matchsticks we sometimes called them.

Comment: @Sparky256 It's getting all too easy these days. I remember opamps [like these](https://youtu.be/mEFdADrU9MA) -- although that one is too easy/nice. The early ones were bigger, of course. Now? You've got 50 cent MCUs in 1's, 50 cent opamps in 1's, and just a few dollars buys a CPLD and a few more dollars gets you a fantastic sea of logic blocks -- FPGA. There's an IC for most any power supply need, most any timing need, ... It's just "plug and play," today. No real need to understand anything much. Which means you can get your secretary doing electronics design over a weekend, web searching.

Comment: @jonk I love all the new stuff. GHZ logic and 144 pin tsop are common. The headache is board layout programs like Spectra. Good but expensive. Now that I am retired...

Comment: @Sparky256 I agree with all this new stuff. Sure saves me a lot of time I used to spend. I'm in "high cotton" as they say. Sad thing is the younger folks don't realize just how good they have it, now. No clue at all. It's night and day. The details we had to fathom back then are buried within beautiful ICs now, making nice, idealized snap-connections easy. So that is a "nice to have," today. But it sadly leaves out so much hard-earned knowledge, too. Which brings to mind a personal discussion I had with Dr. Fouts in central Washington -- one of the top chimpanzee communications.specialists.

Comment: @Sparky256 Dr. Fouts was angry about some researchers who used "plastic chips" to fasciliate communication, instead of sign language with hands. He said, "What if the plastic chips aren't handy? The chimps will become frustrated and angry because they cannot communicate. But if they learn instead to use their hands, they always have their hands available to them. So they don't become angry. It is an inexcusable error to teach them with tools they don't always have at hand."

Comment: @Sparky256  My point here is that if you use ICs for everything, you learn nothing. And if you don't have those ICs available to you, you are screwed because you lack the tools with which to **THINK** for yourself. And that's a very sad loss, indeed. (And yes, I drove up to Central Washington University to meet Dr. Fouts, personally. It was a very enlightening period of time and experience for me. I owe him much for what I received from the many hours he offered me and my daughter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out the schematic and gerber(pcb) files provided by the manufacturer.

Following resistors are what is causing you the confusion.

*Through Hole, 0.25W*

Green Box: 10k, Red Box: 2.2ohm, Cyan Box: 10ohm, Yellow Box: 1k

[image: PCB Image showcasing the resistor pointed out by you]

For knowing these resistors relevance, it is good to check the schematic and find out their usage, if particular resistor values are not available, could something else be used or not.

Following schematic file shows the colored resistors.
[image]

Following are the points:

1. 1k resistor: Used for LED, so within **1-2 kohm** range, any resistor could be used. Only brightness intensity would decrease.
2. 10k resistor: As they are behaving for pull-up functions, could be used in the range of **10-12 kohm**, it will not impact your circuit.
3. 2.2ohm,10ohm resistors are used for 3.3V supply protection. **Higher value may not be recommended** as they would be limiting the current required. *Slightly smaller value* than specified could be used but should not go beyond 10%.

Commenting about the power rating, it is good to use *higher wattage rating resistor* than specified, if space is available on PCB. It looks like **0.5W resistors also it can support**, if 0.25W resistors are not available.

Comment: If I'm seeing things correctly, the red box one on that pic is 5%. Markings seem to be "red red gold gold", meaning 22 * 0.1 multiplier = 2.2 ohm. The last gold being 5% tolerance. (And yeah the THR resistor color codes might just be one of the dumbest things ever invented...)

Comment: Yes, that is right. All the resistors used are of 5% tolerance. I don't think 10%(that's a lot) variation could be found today to buy. It is better to buy 1-5% tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

The 0.25W is the wattage that the resistor should be able to withstand. E.g. it can do 10mA (Milliampere) at 25V (Volts) because 0,25W = 10mA * 25V (from P = U * I).
Generally: More wattage is better.

The 10% is the maximum the tolerance that is allowed. E.g. that allowes for resistors that are labeld "1kΩ" to be between 900Ω and 1100Ω. So a 1kΩ resistor with 5% tolerance (or even less tolerance) will be well within specs.
Generally: Less tolerance is better

Conclusion: You can use any 2.2Ω / 10Ω / 1kΩ resistor with *at least* 0.25W and *a maximum of* 10%.

Adittionally you should look out for the formfactor of the resistor. SMD or THT? How big (as in "5mm long")? You need to know these values if you want to solder it to a pcb.

Comment: The wattage example is a bit misleading. None of the three resistors will have 10mA when 25V are across them, only a 2,5kΩ. P = I² * R or P = U² / R might be the better formular to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

- Visit the web page some component vendor. In this case I used Digikey.
- Click "passives" -> "resistors" -> "chip resistors", assuming SMD.
- Enter filters: resistance 2.2 ohm, power 0.25W, tolerance 1%.
- 63 suggestions, such as this: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/ERJ-8RQF2R2V/P2-2RTR-ND/250222

Very easy. The only actual electronics knowledge you need in order to do this, is that 250mW is usually 1210 or larger SMD packages. The above one was a 1206, but traditionally 1206 only goes up to 125mW.